# CakePHP: How to automagically set associated model ID for inserts/updates?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Good evening!  I'm a bit confused by the magic of CakePHP.  Some of it is amazing, but there is a tricky bit confusing me.  I have a User Model, and an associated UserBasicInfo model:

```
    class User extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'User';
        public $hasOne = array(
            'UserBasicInfo' => array(
                'className' => 'UserBasicInfo',
                'dependent' => true
            )
        );

class UserBasicInfo extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'users_basic_info';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'id'
        )
    );
```

The association is good, it automatically joins and whatnot.  How would I tell the UserBasicInfo model what it's ID is, if it has a record, when doing inserts? It may not always have a record, as I don't force the user to add this info, and I don't like the idea of adding a record full of blank data.  Below is edit_basic_information method in my UserController:

```
    public function edit_basic_information($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $test = $this->User->read();

                    echo '<pre>';
            print_r($test);
            echo '</pre>';
        if (!$this->User->exists())
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));

        //if(empty($this->data))
//          $this->data = $this->User->findById($this->User->id);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
//          $success = false;
            $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
//          $duplicate = $this->User->find('first', 
//              array(
//                  'conditions' => 
//                      array(
//                          'UserBasicInfo.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
//                      )
//              )
//          );
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->request->data);
            echo '</pre>';
//          if($duplicate) {
//              $success = $this->User->updateALL($this->request->data);
//          } else {
                $success = $this->User->saveALL($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
//          }
            if ($success) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The info has been saved'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The info could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set('countries', $this->ChoicesCountries->find('list'));
    }
```

As you can see above, I've tried a few things.  With all the magic that Cake has, doing something like an extra database call for a duplicate check makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.  Also, $this->data is overwritten on submit - It's good for pre-populating previous answers though.  I've also though of adding a hidden id field, but then I just have to add validation, to make sure the ID matches the Auth id.  Not a problem, but it really seems like there is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading of the CakePHP docs, I realized this was somewhat of a silly question.  The save/saveALL methods are only going off the request data I give to them, which will only have fields I specified in the view.  It will not arbitrarily add data to the request->data array.

I solved the problem by changing my primaryKey in the model (wasn't part of the question, but was causing a problem once I figured out the solution), and then adding

```
$this->request->data['UserBasicInfo']['user_id'] = $user['UserBasicInfo']['user_id'];
```

to the method.